# Terminology of functions in $L_2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, terminology, fourier-analysis

I am reading a text that states

> ... any function in $L_2(0,\pi)$ has a Fourier sine series that
>   converges to it in $L_2(0,\pi)$ ...

Unfortunately no definition of $L_2$ is given.  What does $L_2$ (or $L_n$) mean in this context?  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that a function $$f\in L_2(0,\pi)$$ if $$\int_0^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx < \infty.$$

Similar for $L_n$ except the square is replaced with an $n$.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Is the read "L-two"?  What exactly is this notation called (i.e., does Wikipedia have an article on it)?

Comment: @Doubt Yes it is correct to read the notation as "L-two". If you would like to research this further search for $L_p$ space on wikipedia.

Comment: Great, thanks again!